# HTML - How do I insert a <span></span> tag into each line of a <pre></pre> block without hard coding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was just trying to add line numbers at the beginning of source code using CSS.
I realized the effect I wanted, as follows:

[image: Effect implemented]

However, the HTML code required continual use of `<span>...</span>` tags:

```
<pre class="code">
  <span>var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");</span>
  <span>for(var i = 0; i &lt; links.length; i++){</span>
  <span>  links[i].onclick=function(){</span>
  <span>   alert(i+1);</span>
  <span>  };</span>
  <span>}</span>
</pre>
```

With the `span` tags positioned at home/end of lines I can let the line numbers show as expected.
But I think there must be another better solution to prevent me adding all these `span` tags hard-coded, maybe using Javascript, or jQuery I don't mind but don't know how. Please help.

NOTE:
My problem is not how to display line numbers when the `<span>` tags are already there. Instead, I wanted to know if the origin HTML code contains NO `<span>` tags, how can I automatically add them into the suitable places and so I can apply the CSS styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have combined @Stewartside answer with what you have actually asked for.

Below you can see a simple plain JavaScript to replace any line in element with **code** class to be wrapped in **span** which applies @Stewartside css.

```js
var codeElement = document.getElementsByClassName("code"); //array of code blocks
var formattedCode = codeElement[0].textContent.replace("\r\n", "\n").split("\n");
var codeLength = formattedCode.length;
formattedCode.forEach(function(line, index, array) {
  if (codeLength - 1 == index) return; 
  array[index] = "<span>" + line + "</span>";
});

codeElement[0].innerHTML = formattedCode.join("\n");

$(".code-jquery").each(function(index, codeElement) {
  var formattedCode = $(codeElement).html().replace("\r\n", "\n").split("\n");
  
  var codeLength = formattedCode.length;
  $(codeElement).text("");
  $.each(formattedCode, function(index, line) {
    if (codeLength - 1 == index) return;
    $(codeElement).append("<span>" + line + "</span>\n")
  });
});
```

```css
pre {
  background: #eee;
  counter-reset: section; /* Reset the counter to 0 for each new pre */
}
pre span:before {
  counter-increment: section; /* Increment the section counter*/
  content: counter(section); /* Display the counter */
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #777;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #777
}

pre.code-jquery span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<pre class="code">
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
  for(var i = 0; i &lt; links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function() {
     alert(i+1);
   };
  }
</pre>

//jQuery version
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre class="code-jquery">
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
  for(var i = 0; i &lt; links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function() {
     alert(i+1);
   };
  }
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using CSS counters

This does not require any JavaScript (or jQuery) which means no need for each libraries or scripts and was introduced way back in CSS 2.1 so has great browser support across the board.

```css
pre {
  background: #eee;
  counter-reset: section; /* Reset the counter to 0 for each new pre */
}
pre span:before {
  counter-increment: section; /* Increment the section counter*/
  content: counter(section); /* Display the counter */
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #777;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #777
}
```

```html
<pre class="code">
  <span>var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");</span>
  <span>for(var i = 0; i &lt; links.length; i++){</span>
  <span>  links[i].onclick=function(){</span>
  <span>   alert(i+1);</span>
  <span>  };</span>
  <span>}</span>
</pre>

<pre class="code">
  <span>var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");</span>
  <span>for(var i = 0; i &lt; links.length; i++){</span>
  <span>  links[i].onclick=function(){</span>
  <span>   alert(i+1);</span>
  <span>  };</span>
  <span>}</span>
</pre>
```

Comment: **You didn't get the idea..** What I want is to **save** the `<span>` tags and using JS or other tools to make the tags need dynamically inserted..

Comment: @HaoYellow apologies, your question wasn't the clearest. In terms of adding them dynamically, that would be exceedingly difficult because how would you write a function that can read when a new line needs to occur.

Answer (score 0):

So you basically need to append a `span` before each line. Here is the [codepen link](http://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/RGJPvk). I am currently using `jQuery's insertBefore()` method for it.

See below for the explanation of the code :- 
`$('.code')` will give you the `pre tag`. Now the jQuery `.find()` method will give you all the spans inside the pre tag. Now jQuery `.each()` function is basically `a for loop` ( in simple terms ) which will loop for all the span tags inside the pre tag.
`.insertBefore()` function simply inserts whatever there is in the selector to the element mentioned `inside the function`.

```js
var iCount = 1;
$('.code').find('span').each(function(){
  
  $( "<span>"+iCount+"| </span>" ).insertBefore( this);
  iCount++;
});
```

```css
pre{
   background: #eee
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre class="code">
  <span>var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");</span>
  <span>for(var i = 0; i &lt; links.length; i++){</span>
  <span>  links[i].onclick=function(){</span>
  <span>   alert(i+1);</span>
  <span>  };</span>
  <span>}</span>
</pre>
```

Comment: My problem is not how to display line numbers when the <span> tags are already there. Instead, I wanted to know if the origin HTML code is:

Comment: (Continued. I hit "enter" and made a commit!) I meant, when the origin code contained no <span>, how can I add them automatically?

Comment: @HaoYellow ya its `possible` to do that in a `similar manner`. Can you share your exact code where there are no `spans` initially ?

Comment: The `span` version is `<pre><span>line of span</span>...next_spans...</pre>`, which is not what I wanted since when the `pre` inner content is dynamical, I cannot add the `span`'s. What I wanted is like this: `<pre>line of span...next_lines...</pre>`.

Comment: I just @ you but I am not sure if I did successfully.. Yeah I am a Stackoverflow newbie.